# Por que o pattern Open Session In View é considerado um anti-pattern?

Tags: java, jpa

Gostaria de saber por que muitos desenvolvedores e arquitetos consideram o padrão ***Open Session In View*** um *anti-pattern*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## O que é *Open Session In View*?

É um padrão usado com frameworks de **Mapeamento Objeto-Relacional** como o Hibernate e outras implementações de JPA.

Um objeto gerenciado por um framework JPA é conhecido como **Entidade**. Uma entidade pode ter relacionamentos com outras entidades e esses relacionamentos são resolvidos automaticamente pelo framework.

O problema é que os dados de entidades relacionadas por padrão são recuperados apenas quando efetivamente o código executa o método que recupera o valor. Se a chamada for feita após a conexão com o banco ter sido encerrada ocorre o famoso erro `LazyInitializationException` ou equivalente.

No padrão ***Open Session In View***, a "sessão" (conexão´) fica aberta até o final da requisição, possibilitando que os dados de relacionamentos sejam recuperados a qualquer momento, incluindo durante a renderização da *View*, pois é um momento em que muitos dados são acessados.

## Quando este padrão é usado?

Por exemplo, se existem duas *views* que usam o mesmo serviço para recuperar uma entidade, mas somente uma delas acessa uma outra entidade relacionada, as soluções poderiam ser:

1. Carregar sempre os dados desse relacionamento, porém é um desperdício pois se sabe que em algumas situações os dados serão desnecessários.
2. Criar outro serviço que já retorne os dados do relacionamento, porém isso pode levar a código duplicado.
3. Permitir que os dados sejam recuperados fora do serviço. Este é o padrão! Isso significa que quando uma View acessar, por exemplo, `cliente.getEndereco()` o framework irá buscar o endereço do cliente no banco de dados.

## Por que ele é um *anti-pattern*?

### Ele "quebra" o encapsulamento das camadas da arquitetura.

Será necessário código implementado na camada de controle ou da View para gerenciar conexão e transação com o banco de dados.

Além de ferir o princípio do "menor conhecimento possível", temos um forte acoplamento entre o código da View e os serviços disponíveis no *core* do sistema.

Isso pode dificultar a realização de testes unitários e a reutilização dos serviços em outros locais.

### O desempenho e a escalabilidade pode ser afetados

O padrão exige que a transação e, consequentemente, a conexão com o banco de dados fique aberta até o final da requisição. Mas segurar um recurso tão essencial pode causa impactos enormes no desempenho do sistema, principalmente se houver vários acessos simultâneos.

Fazendo um chute bem grosseiro, poderíamos dizer que se as transações demorarem o dobro para serem finalizadas por causa do tempo de geração da *view*, o sistema poderá atender a metade dos usuários comparando com uma versão que encerre a transação na camada de serviços.

Só que geralmente isso é bem pior. Se a transação continua aberta durante a view, ela pode estar bloqueando recursos importantes de vários outros usuários. **As transações devem ser fechadas o mais rapidamente possível.**

Trabalhei em um sistema que tinha um processamento "pesado" de mais ou menos 1 minuto. Em teoria ele funcionaria em paralelo, mas notamos que todas as requisições de diferentes usuários estavam sendo enfileiradas. O motivo? Um *lock* em uma tabela causada pelo incremento do ID no início do serviço. A resolução foi simples: realizar o processamento pesado fora da transação.

### Falta de transparência

Quando a sessão fica "solta" durante a requisição, é mais fácil que problemas passem despercebidos. O desenvolvedor se acomoda em saber que suas entidades podem fazer de "tudo" depois que são retornadas pela camada de serviços.

A tendência é que o número de queries executadas durante a renderização das views aumente sem controle. Até o sistema começar a ser usado em produção por vários usuários, este problema irá passar totalmente despercebido.

A não ser que o desenvolvedor esteja sempre com o log ligado e analise todas as queries geradas. E isso deverá ser feito sempre que a *view* mudar, pois novas chamadas a novos atributos podem fazer com que novas queries sejam executadas a qualquer momento!

Um JSP com uma EL aparentemente inocente pode na verdade ocupar 99% do tempo de resposta.

### Ele é usado por preguiça

Pode ser preguiça de refatorar os serviços, de argumentar com outros desenvolvedores para criar uma arquitetura melhor, de estudar um padrão melhor e assim por diante.

A questão é que a camada de serviços deveria retornar os dados prontos para a *view* de forma a não necessitar de processamento adicional. Só que para isso o desenvolvedor precisaria analisar os dados e ver o que vai ser necessário.

Então, da mesma forma que é mais fácil criar uma variável global para usar em todo lugar, deixa-se a sessão aberta para ser usada "quando for necessário".

### Lidando com erros

Se a transação for finalizada após a renderização da View, isso tratá uma complexidade maior para o tratamento de possíveis erros.

Imagine que enquanto uma tela é gerada ocorre um erro numa das queries, talvez porque a coluna de uma tabela foi excluída. Como isso será tratado?

Numa aplicação web, por exemplo, isso vai exigir um filtro que faça tratamento desse tipo de erro.

### Casos excepcionais são um grande problema

Imagine que um determinado serviço precisa ler dados de um banco de dados para outro. Isso vai exigir duas conexões e, talvez, uma transação distribuída.

O problema é que sua arquitetura já está acoplada, então teria que ser feita alguma gambiarra para abrir outra conexão, com outra transação desvinculada da primeira, ou coisa do tipo.

## Conclusões

Particularmente, não vejo vantagens e situações onde seria necessário o uso do padrão ***Open Session In View***.

Por outro lado, em aplicações Desktop ele poderia ser usado sem maiores problemas porque não há a questão de concorrência e escalabilidade citadas, embora a separação das camadas continue a ser quebrada.

Do meu ponto de vista, o desenvolvedor deve se preocupar com quais dados serão usados após a chamada de cada serviço e forçar isso, por exemplo usando *fetch joins*.

E padrões como *Transfer Object* são nossos amigos nesses momentos em que precisamos trazer dados a mais do banco sem alterar nossas entidades ou abusar do uso de relacionamentos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!